# T-SQL - Group by Date within Date Range with counts on two columns

Tags: t-sql, cross-join

I have a issue tracking database.  I need to be able to provide a report of all the issues opened and closed for each day within a date range.

I've been able to produce results for one column at a time... all open or all closed.
I really would like to do it all in one shot instead of having to provide results in two parts when it's really one report.

The columns in question are dteOpen (datetime), dteClosed(datetime).

### Here is what I have for returning all opened.

```
Declare @dt1 datetime = '1/1/1900', 
Declare @dt2 datetime = '1/1/1900',
Declare @tT int = 0IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempDate') IS NoT NULL  
      DROP TABLE #TempDate

;WITH ctedaterange 
     AS (SELECT [rn]=Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
         FROM   sys.objects a 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects b 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects c 
                CROSS JOIN sys.objects d) 
SELECT CAST(Dateadd(dd, rn, @dt1) AS DATE) As DateRange
into #TempDate
FROM   ctedaterange 
WHERE  [rn] <= Datediff(dd, @dt1, @dt2)

Select td.DateRange,Count(ID)as countNumber 

from #TempDate td
LEFT outer JOIN tblProblemslist pl
ON CAST(pl.dtmOpen AS DATE) = td.DateRange
AND    dtmOpen between @dt1 and @dt2
AND ticketType = @tT
Group by td.DateRange
Order by td.DateRange
```

Comment: Can you provide structure of tables, test data and expected result. It is easy way to do it using http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just join `tblProblemsList` again but with the conditions for closed issues. Then you can add another `COUNT` to your query.

Without knowing more about your table structure, I'm guessing you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @from       datetime = '12/1/2012'; 
DECLARE @through    datetime = '12/31/2012';
DECLARE @then       datetime = DATEADD(dd, -1, @from);
Declare @ticketType int = 0;

DECLARE @dateRange  table
(
    dateRange   date
    , id        int IDENTITY
)

-- use a loop to populate the @daterange table var
-- rather than selecting from sys.object and
-- using a ranking function
WHILE   @then < @through
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @dateRange (dateRange) VALUES (DATEADD(dd, 1, @then))
    SET         @then = DATEADD(dd, 1, @then)
END

SELECT      dateRange.dateRange
            , COUNT(listOfOpened.id) AS countOfOpened
            , COUNT(listOfClosed.id) AS countOfClosed
FROM        @dateRange AS dateRange
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tblProblemsList AS listOfOpened
                ON  CAST(listOfOpened.dtmOpen AS DATE) = dateRange.dateRange
                AND listOfOpened.dtmOpen BETWEEN @from AND @through
                AND listOfOpened.ticketType = @ticketType
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tblProblemsList AS listOfClosed
                ON  CAST(listOfClosed.dtmClosed AS DATE) = dateRange.dateRange
                AND listOfClosed.dtmClosed BETWEEN @from AND @through
                AND listOfClosed.ticketType = @ticketType
GROUP BY    dateRange.dateRange
ORDER BY    dateRange.dateRange
```